# If I Reserve Capacity for a Windows Server macine am i charged for the windiows License fees?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

It seems like I shouldn't, but you never know and the windows fees a as expensive as the machine itself.

The docs don't mention this, but maybe it's obvious:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview

Does anyone have first-hand or authoritative knowledge?

Comment: Read the contract you signed.

Comment: you can also check this [FAQ about Microsoft licenses.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing-faq)